# Ruby to_json :methods arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render-to-response

I am using the `to_json` method on an object, and trying to get the `:methods` argument to work. I have a method on my model (Drop) called `is_favorited_by_user?`. This method takes an argument of the `current_user`, and then checks to see if the drop is favorited by the user. How can I pass this argument through the `to_json` method.

```
render :json => @drops.to_json(:methods => :is_favorited_by_user?(current_user))
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can add `current_user` attribute to your model and set it before executing `to_json`

```
  attr_accessor :current_user

  def is_favorited_by_user?(user=nil)
    user ||= current_user
    # rest of your code
  end


@drops.current_user = current_user
render :json => @drops.to_json(:methods => :is_favorited_by_user?)
```

Comment: How do I extend this solution when I'm doing render :json => Drop.all in the index action. Where do I assign the current_user?

Comment: `cattr_accessor :current_user` in model and then `Model.current_user = current_user` in controller.

Comment: Assigning your model to a class attribute won't work if your environment is multi-threaded. You could be in the process of converting something to JSON and then the current_user all of a sudden changes and now half your JSON is for one user and half is for another.

Answer (score 4):

The methods `to_json` takes aren't intended to be ones that take arguments, but just "getter" methods. (Typically the ones created based on your db attributes.)

See examples here, none pass arguments:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json

If you want to do something custom, you'll need to create a method that builds up the hash of info you want, then convert that hash to json.

Comment: Is there a way that I can get the current_user variable within my Model, so I don't need to pass the argument?

Comment: @JamesFinley Models are not (and should not be) aware of the state of controllers or http request. current_user is part of the request and should not be exposed to models in a global way due to the multithreaded issue stated above. It should be passed only as a method parameter.