# Get absolute URL for paperclip attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Is it possible to get the absolute URI for a Paperclip attachment? Right now, the problem is that the production environment is deployed in a sub-URI (on Passenger: `RackBaseURI`), but `<paperclip attachment>.url` returns the Rails-app relative URI (`/system/images/...`). Is there a way to get the absolute URI for Paperclip attachments?

I'm using Paperclip v2.7 and Rails 3.2.8.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

try

```
URI.join(request.url, @model.attachment_name.url)
```

or

```
URI(request.url) + @model.attachment_name.url
```

It's safe if you use S3 or absolute url.

Update: this answer is better than mine ;) https://stackoverflow.com/a/21027839/683157

Comment: undefined local variable or method `request' for #<ModelName:0x000001083fd438>

Comment: @kokemomuke you can't do that in a model — `request` is only available in controllers and views

Comment: I wonder how can I do this inside Grape Entities... request isn't available there also. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 41):

```
asset_url(model.attachment_name.url(:style))
```

[Relevant github issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/584)

Comment: It's for Rails 4+ I think?

Comment: `asset_url` cannot be used in controller directly, but `URI.join` can :-)

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_url

Answer (score 20):

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/584#issuecomment-1985865), it is cleaner to use `ActionController::Base.asset_host` so it would result the helper:

```
  def add_host_prefix(url)
    URI.join(ActionController::Base.asset_host, url)
  end
```

This supposes you have in every `/config/environments/<environment>.rb` file the following:

```
Appname::Application.configure do

  # ....

  config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000' # Locally

  # ....

end
```

Answer (score 6):

The most widely applicable way of doing this is to first define your asset hosts in the relevant config/environment file:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assethost.com"
config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://assethost.com"
```

Then in views and mailers:

```
asset_url(model.attachment.url(:style))
```

In the console:

```
helper.asset_url(model.attachment.url(:style))
```

In a model:

```
ApplicationController.helpers.asset_url(model.attachment.url(:style))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
<%= image_tag "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{@model.attachment_name.url(:attachment_style)}" %>
```

Or make a helper method to wrap it.

```
def absolute_attachment_url(attachment_name, attachment_style = :original)
  "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{attachment_name.url(attachment_style)}"
end
```

And use it like this:

```
<%= image_tag absolute_attachment_url(attachment_name, :attachment_style)}" %>
```

Ex: Model = Person (@person), attachment_name = avatar, style = :thumb

```
<%= image_tag absolute_attachment_url(@person.avatar, :thumb)}" %>
```

Comment: attention. this won't work when having `config.action_controller.asset_host` set as it will give you duplicate/screwed protocol + host.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't solve the original poster's problem exactly (it operates in the view, not the model), but may be helpful for people who are trying to "get absolute URL for paperclip attachment" within their view: In the same way that

```
image_tag(user.avatar.url(:large))
```

puts the image itself into your view,

```
image_url(user.avatar.url(:large))
```

returns just the URL you'll need if you want to link to the asset directly (e.g. in a `link_to` call).

Comment: "The Attachment#url method is misleading since it returns a relative path (like the Routes _path methods) not a full url (like the Routes _url methods). Googling turns up several "answers", but they are all hacks." https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/584#issue-1548822

Answer (score 2):

You can add to your `application.rb` (or for specific enviroment in `config/environments/*`):

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    url: "http://my.address.com/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style.:extension",
    path: ':rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style.:extension',
}
```

Restart and reimport your images.

PS: obviously you can replace http://my.address.com with an environment variable.