# Call instance method from associate model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, model-associations

This question comes as a consequense of a previous one ([Return url from paperclip to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440643/return-url-from-paperclip-to-json)). I am summing it up in order to be easier to follow and also because this is just a part of the above mentioned one. I have a CMS system that uses paperclip for multiple image uploading. My code is

**asset.rb**

```
 attr_accessible :asset_content_type, :asset_file_name, :asset_file_size, :asset_updated_at, :place_id, :asset
  belongs_to :place
  has_attached_file :asset

   validates_attachment :asset, :presence => true,
  :content_type => { :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png'] },
  :size => { :in => 0..1.megabytes }

def asset_url
asset.url(:original)
end
```

**place.rb**

```
has_many :assets
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true

def avatar_url
asset_url
end
```

**places_controller**

```
def overall_photos
    @places = Place.all
    render :json => @places.to_json(:methods => [:avatar_url])
    end
```

The error I get when I try to access ...places/overall_photos.json is {"status":"500","error":"undefined local variable or method `asset_url' for #\u003CPlace:0x007f163b67d8a8\u003E"} so it seems tat I can't access the instance method of asset.rb through the associate model place.rb. Can anyone point me to the right direction? I even tried to make asset_url a class method but still no luck.

Comment: Given that a place has_many assets, what's your intent about what `asset_url` should return for a given place?

Comment: To call an instance method for a particular class (e.g. asset), you need an instance of that class.

Comment: Preferably I would like all asset_urls returned.

Comment: I understand that but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def avatar_url
  assets.map(&:asset_url)
end
```

This should give you what you want according to your comment

Comment: I see you figured it out! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you want all asset URLs:

```
def asset_urls
  self.assets.map {|a| a.asset_url }
end
```

But you probably want only one as an avatar, so I'd use

```
def avatar_url
  self.assets.first.asset_url if self.assets.first  #to avoid calling asset_url on Nil
end
```