# Putting instance method results (with arguments) into active_model_serializers

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I'm making a JSON API and want to serialize a `recipe` record from my database.  In the JSON response, I want to include the output of `@recipe.is_favorited_by?(current_user)` along with some of the `recipe`'s attributes.

I saw from [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) that I could call: `render json: @recipe, methods: :is_favorited_by?` - but I'm not sure how to pass in current_user as an argument.

What call would I need to make in order to include the results of `@recipe.is_favorited_by?(current_user`) in the response?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `current_user` attribute to your model & set it before  your json execute.

See stackoverflow question link [Ruby to_json :methods arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745607/ruby-to-json-methods-arguments)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm wondering if there's a more extensible way of doing this.  If there are other methods that require other arguments, I would have to do this for each one if I use this approach.